# What will be `.floatValue` in swift

Tags: swift

I have searched enough in the web but failed to find any solution to this problem. It is a very basic thing in Objective C but I am not able to find the swift version of this.

I have an array like below:

```
arrSearchResult = [["name":"Adam Richards","occupation":"Architect","address":"Kolkata","status":"Pending","points":"4.8"],
                       ["name":"Rupindar Bains","occupation":"Photography, Interior Decorator","address":"Pune","status":"Accepted","points":"2.9"],
                       ["name":"Ajit Kolethe","occupation":"Finance Expert, Payroll","address":"Mumbai","status":"Rejected","points":"1.2"],
                       ["name":"Bob Grant","occupation":"Finance Service","address":"Kolkata","status":"Pending","points":"4.8"],
                       ["name":"Rachel Hunter","occupation":"Photography, Interior Decorator","address":"Pune","status":"Accepted","points":"3.5"],
                       ["name":"Sylvia Sanders","occupation":"Finance Expert, Payroll","address":"Mumbai","status":"Pending","points":"1.7"],
                       ["name":"Brittany Ramirez","occupation":"Graphic Designer, Photography","address":"Gurgaon","status":"Rejected","points":"2.2"],
                       ["name":"Xanadu Lee","occupation":"Chef, Travel Guide","address":"Mumbai","status":"Accepted","points":"4.8"]]
```

In every index in the array there is a Dictionary. As you can see there is a key in the Dictionary as "points". I am storing some float value as String with respect to that key.

Now I want to check the value if it is greater then or less than to a particular value or not.

In Objc I can write,

```
if([[arrSearchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"points"].floatValue < 2.0) {
    //Do something
}
```

I have tried:

```
let point = (arrSearchResult.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "points") as AnyObject
if Int(point as! NSNumber) > 2.0 {
    //Do something
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Comment: Given your dictionaries have static keys, you should really be using an array of structs instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (safe) Swift 3 equivalent is

```
if let result = arrSearchResult[indexPath.row] as? [String:String], 
   let pointString = result["points"], 
   let point = Double(pointString), point > 2.0 {

}
```

The array contains dictionaries with `String` keys and `String` values. The value for key `points` is also a string. The code checks all types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir, I have got the logic clear now but I am not getting the syntax clear. Can you please make understood the if condition clearly? and if I want the point to be in between two values, e.g 2.0 to 4.0 then how will the if condition look like. @vadian

Comment: The point is the compiler needs to know all types of subscripted objects. Each condition (except the last) unwraps an optional value on success. The first one checks if the dictionary has the right type, the second one gets the `String` for key `points` and the third converts the `String` to `Double`. If you want a range, add another condition `... , point >= 2.0, point < 4.0 { ... (Boolean) conditions are *AND*ed.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Now its totally clear. Thank you so so much. @vadian

Comment: @iPeter for a range better to use the range pattern operator `2.0..<4.0 ~= point`

Comment: Thank you sir. I have now used this syntax. @LeoDabus

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
if Double(point as! String)! > 2.0 {
    ....
}
```

Your `point` is actually stored as a `String`.

The numeric types in Swift are *strongly typed*. For instance, you can't directly compare an `Int` to `Double` without a type conversion first. The compiler error you are getting warns you about this:

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Comment: @Sulthan Haha, you are right :) Thanks, answer fixed.